# Insert text into a div with jquery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, text

I'm trying to get jquery to load the text from a text file into a div for a blog, but it's not working at all. any help?

this is what I'm using (what I've seen other's use). Also, I'm not testing it locally.

```
$("#content").load("articlename.txt");
```

update:
is there any way for it to keep the enters as breaks?

Comment: where does the text file reside?

Comment: make sure you have included jquery library file and check also the path of your text file

Comment: are you getting any errors? Please check console logs.

Comment: in the root with the index

Comment: I've included the jquery library

Comment: I'm getting this one error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined,    
no clue why

Comment: Wrap your code inside document.ready

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a no direct way to get data from external file in jquery.
But via ajax its possible.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#loadData").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "articlename.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
        }
    });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#content").load("articlename.txt"); 
});
```

Wrap your call inside document.ready.